# Django Template Tagging inserting a single value from a ListView

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

So I am undertaking a website project and I am having some issues with one page.

I essentially load NBA teams wins and losses onto a page and make my own makeshift standings ladder.

The data loaded from my model is as follows:

#### MODEL.PY

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    wins = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    losses = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I use the ListView in my views.py file as follows:

#### VIEWS.PY

```
class LadderListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    #this defaults to looking for the models name html so in this case team_list.html
    # so i changed it to template_name variable
    template_name = 'merchbet/ladder_list.html'
    model = models.Team
```

and render the urls.py file as follows:

```
path('ladder/', views.LadderListView.as_view(), name='ladder_list'),
```

all of this successfully works.

When I get to my html code I am able to the teams, and their win/loss records to print to the website with template tagging, but I am looking to inject one line at the bottom which shows the "Last Updated: {{ team.created_date }}.

This is not working and I am not getting an errors, the "{{ team.created_date }}" just shows nothing on the url page.

I have looked through the docs and can not see what I am doing wrong.

This is my html code:

#### LADDER_LIST.HTML

```
{% extends 'merchbet/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">


<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Team</td>
<td>Wins</td>
<td>Losses</td>
</tr>
{% for teams in object_list %}
<tr>
<td>{{ teams.team_name }}</td>
<td>{{ teams.wins }}</td>
<td>{{ teams.losses }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<h2 style="color:white;"> testing {{ team.created_date }}</h2>

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have anything called `team` in your template.

If you just want to display the value from a single team in the lst, and don't care which one, just grab the first or last:

```
{{ object_list.0.created_date }}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to edit your models and that should fix your problem

```
class Team(models.Model):
    ....
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True) #when you first add team
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False) #when you update 
    class Meta :
        ordering = ["-updated","created_date"]
```

Comment: This isn't what I am trying to do, all teams will be updated at once, so all I need is to show one update tag on the website, not the back end. This is more for the user to know when the wins/losses was last updated... more a question about the template tagging, I am pretty sure I am doing the rest ok?

Comment: you can just add the updated to the models and use  {{ team.updated }}  or {{ team.updated|timesince }}

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately, just for the record {{team.losses}}, {{team.wins}}, etc all do not work in that position, so I think the issue is somewhere else....

and yes, I did migrate after making the changes that you suggested above

Comment: it's not working because  you aren't including it inside the loop  {{ team.updated }} should be inside the for loop

Comment: That is my question, I don't want to print it 30 times for every team, I want to print it once at the bottom.

Is that possible?

Comment: This is relevant becuase I know all teams are updated at the same time....

Comment: i dont think it's possible in list view because your getting a queryset back not an instance ,

Comment: Ok no worries, is there a way to do it at all that you know of?